# Filiter ghost touch screen events

Tags: xorg, touchscreen

With Ubuntu 20.04 Xorg, how can I ignore touch events from a screen region? I have a Dell S2240T touch screen monitor with ghost touch events along a short length of one column. If I could list pixels or a region to ignore, the touch screen may be usable. It's fine if the fix also requires mouse events from the region to be ignored. Thank you

**Update**
Using `evtest` attached to the touch screen device I can see the MT_ABS_POSITION_X values are consistent for the ghost press events. I've found `xevie(3)` which looks promising, but maybe someone will know an existing way to filter the events.